# Apply same Keras Tensorflow preprocessing transform to several images

Tags: tensorflow, keras, preprocessor

I'm currently building my own custom generator with data augmentation. I have to apply the same transformation to two images, the train one and the target one, but functions only works one by one. Any ideas how to apply the exact transformation in both images?
This is one function I'm trying:

tf.keras.preprocessing.image.random_zoom

The code for the generator:

```
def generator(data, batch_size = 32, data_augmentation = False):
batch_number = 0
while True:
    original_train = []
    original_target = []
    train = []
    target = []
    if batch_number * batch_size >= data.shape[0]:
            batch_number = 0        
    for x in train_pd.values[batch_number * batch_size: (batch_number + 1) * batch_size ]:
        train_image = load_image_as_array(train_path+'images/'+x[0]+'.png').reshape(101,101,1)
        target_image = load_image_as_array(train_path+'masks/'+x[0]+'.png').reshape(101,101,1)
        original_train.append(train_image)
        original_target.append(target_image)
        if data_augmentation:
            train_image = random_zoom(train_image, (.25,.25))
            target_image = random_zoom(target_image, (.25,.25))
        train.append(train_image)
        target.append(target_image)            
    batch_number += 1
    yield np.array(train), np.array(target), np.array(original_train), np.array(original_target)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. It seems that it applies the exact transformation besides you call the function two times.